# How does Python pass keyword changes values in list?

Tags: python

I have one small program in Python. I have created list and I am passing it as function parameter. According to me it should give output as 1 2 3 4 5. But it is giving me `5 2 3 4 5` as output. If I am just writing 'pass' keyword inside for loop then it should not do anything.Then why is that changing my output?

Here is my code:

```
def fun1(list1):
    for list1[0] in list1: 
        pass
list2=[1,2,3,4,5]
fun1(list2)
print(list2)
```

Comment: What on earth do you expect  *for list1[0] in list1:* to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loops sets the loop variable `list1[0]` to each value in the list `list1`. After it has finished, the loop variable contains whatever its value was in the last iteration, which in this case is `5`. If you don't want your loop to have this weird side effect, don't use an existing variable (like `list1[0]`) as the loop variable. I have never seen anyone do this before: it is a very odd thing to do.